# coalesce of first 2 rows using R

Tags: r

I have a data set that is imported from excel in the following format.

```
S/N   Category         Test    
      Cat1     Cat2    test1   test2    Quantity   Start_Month    End_Month
 1     A        C        T1      T2        1        Feb             March
 2     B        D        T2      T3        4        Jun             Dec
```

The issue here is that the first 2 rows are the headers and the raw dataset is obtained by the importing of excel sheet where they merge cells for some of the headers and for others, it has 2 rows as the header instead. for instance category, the correct headers should be Cat1 and Cat2.

Is there a way for me to combine the first 2 rows by taking the first non empty value of row 1 and row 2? (like Coalesce(row2,row1)?) For instance, for S/N, since the second row is empty, we will take the first row, which is S/N as the correct header.

Edit: An image of the data set in excel is as attached. The rows that are highlighted in yellow is the Header.[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (`dput(head(df))`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
`S/N` Category_Cat1 Category_Cat2 Test_Test1 Test_Test2 Quantity Start_Month End_Month
  <chr> <chr>         <chr>         <chr>      <chr>      <chr>    <chr>       <chr>    
1 1     A             C             T1         T2         1        Feb         Mar      
2 2     B             D             T2         T3         4        Jun         Dec
```

If yes here's the code to do this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(unpivotr)
library(openxlsx)

read.xlsx('FILE_NAME.xlsx', colNames = FALSE) %>%
  as_cells() %>%
  behead('N', 'H1') %>%
  behead('N', 'H2') %>%
  mutate(tmp = str_remove(H2, '\\d')) %>%
  group_by(tmp) %>%
  fill(H1, .direction = 'up') %>%
  fill(H1, .direction = 'down') %>%
  mutate(
    H1 = replace_na(H1, ''),
    H2 = replace_na(H2, ''),
    H = str_c(H1, H2, sep = '_') %>% str_remove('^_|_$')
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(H = H %>% fct_reorder(col)) %>%
  select(H, row, chr) %>%
  spread(H, chr) %>%
  select(-row)
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I am looking for, as a sidenote, can the following code be modified to read multiple sheets in xlsx?

Comment: Ofcourse it can. `read.xlsx` function have `sheet` argument, so you can loop through all sheets and apply this code.